# How to Shrink SQL Server CE Database using SQL

Tags: sql-server-ce

I am using SQL Server CE databases on our clients machines, and I was wondering if there is a way to shrink the database using SQL?

In SQL Server you do this,

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE
```

Is there something like this for SQL Server CE?

Unfortunately I don't have the facility to run this command using C# like this,

```
SqlCeEngine.Shrink
```

without some kind of software change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this via SQL.

You can use my sqlcecmd command line tool to Compact the database (better than shrink):

```
sqlcecmd -d "Data Source=C:\Northwind.sdf" -e compact
```

Comment: But there is no way to do it using SQL? I have a facility to send SQL to our offline users, and that's it. I would have to make a software change of some kind to make the above command work when we schedule it or something along those lines. If that is required then I wouldn't bother with the compact / shrink as it may not be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Before you implement shrink behaviour in your application, you should really consider pros and cons of this action. Shrinking your database file have only one pro: data file will take less storage space. But downside is that indexes in your DB would suffer performance penalty, so most of your queries will be slower. I would advise you against shrinking databases in production. Especially I advise against using auto-shrink feature of SQL Server CE - it may lead to data file corruption in some cases. Good news is that you can completely disable auto-shrink behaviour with parameter "autoshrink threshold = 100" in your connection string.